# When programatically adding google map shapes need way to add rightclick listener event

Tags: google-maps

From the examples I don't see a way to add a rightclick event on a shape I created on the map programatically.  I'm creating maps that are saved to a database, so I'm restoring the shapes.  I see an example where they added a  click event within the 'overlaycomplete' listener event in examples but how do you do this if you are creating the shape?

Comment: Ok, I should have tried a little harder before posting this question.  You just need to add the new listener like so:  google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'rightclick', function (e) {
        alert('Right clicked!');
    });

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it now in a slightly more succinct way:

```js
newShape.addListener('rightclick', function () {
    alert('Right clicked!');
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes that looks to be a much cleaner expression.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is easy.  I just added this code to add the listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'rightclick', function (e) {
        alert('Right clicked!');
    });
```

Where newShape is the new created polygon.